# Don't need to put properties inside the interface?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I think I got a bad book on Objective-C. It said to put variables I'm going to use and make available to other classes inside the interface brackets, and then declare a property of the same thing.

```
@interface appDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>  {
    NSNumber *myNumberOtherClassesCanUse;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *myNumberOtherClassesCanUse;
```

However, I saw another question answered that made me think I didn't have to put them inside the brackets, so I tried that and it still works fine.

I bought another book and it doesn't explain it either, so can someone tell me or point me to documentation on when I have to put them inside the brackets AND make them properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A long and complicated answer:

The class fields, the things inside the interface brackets:

```
@interface MyClass : SomeSuperclass
{
  int someNumber_; /* this stuff */
}
```

add actual bytes to your object. An objective-C class is really, underneath all the fluff, just a large C struct; and these are the fields of that struct. (You can even get at them with `->` style C pointer syntax, although the compiler will yell at you if you do so without an `@public` in there; the correct way to access these fields is by bare name like any other variable.)

A property declaration like:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) int someNumber;
```

is obj-C 2.0 shorthand for a pair of method declarations like:

```
-(int)someNumber;
-(void)setSomeNumber:(int)newNumber;
```

which adds nothing to your class; it just declares to the world that here are some operations that can be performed on this class. By convention, methods like this are supposed to get and set a field value, or at least behave like they do. Having methods like this lets you use the `obj.prop` and `obj.prop = val` dot-syntax to call them.

A synthesize directive:

```
@synthesize someNumber;
```

optionally creates these methods for you at runtime, using standard builtin behaviors (informed by that "nonatomic, assign" stuff), **AND** optionally creates a field of the same name to get and set. A directive like `@synthesize someNumber = someNumber_;` names the created field "someNumber_" instead. If you declared such a field in the @interface block, like I did above, it uses that field; otherwise it quietly inserts an appropriate field of its own. This quiet field insertion is new behavior since the 4.x simulator; before that you had to declare all your fields in the @interface{} block, period.

In summary: @interface{...} describes the physical fields of your object; @property()... describes ways your object is supposed to be used; and @synthesize is shorthand for implementing basic getter/setters and inserting extra fields if needed. I usually let @synthesize do its thing, and leave my @interface{} block empty until I have an actual need to declare a field explicitly, usually to look at it with the debugger.

[as of the latest SDKs, some of the above is dated. In particular, @synthesize is now optional, and instance vars can be declared in the `@implementation` in the .m file.]

Comment: Thanks rgeorge. Does it take any more or less space to just make everything a property?

Comment: Nope. The "field" is the storage, the "property" is how you get at it. making everything a property and letting @synthesize take care of the fields is a perfectly legitimate way to go, although you have to know the difference when it comes time to replace the synthesized accessor methods with something fancier.

Answer (score 1):

You don't generally have to put them in the `@interface` brackets when you are using `@property` and `@synthesize` as the synthesize will create the variable for you if it does not detect a backing ivar declared in the class.

The brilliant `iOS recipes` book states that the iOS device runtime has always had this capability but it was only added to the simulator in iOS 4. So considering the simulator is used a lot in development it is probably just a habit that stuck for some.

And to back that up at the very bottom of this [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17) for `The Objective-C Programming Language`

> There is one key difference: the modern runtime supports instance variable synthesis whereas the legacy runtime does not.

Comment: Thanks Paul.s. I'm going to get the IOS recipes book and I've bookmarked that Apple doc.

Answer (score 0):

Trust your compiler, not your books.